# How to cache clear when user logout in React JS

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class logout extends React.Component {

    executeBasicAuthenticationService() {

    }

    logout(event) {
        this.executeBasicAuthenticationService()
            .then(() => {
                sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME); 
                sessionStorage.clear();
                window.location.href="/";
            })
            .catch(() => {})

    }
```

Comment: What is the issue? You code seems to be ok and clearing sessionStorage.

Comment: After logout when i am clicking back button in browser its taking me to previous page of application. But it should not go to back page as i am clearing cache using function  client.clearStore();. Please let me know how to clear cache in that code

Comment: When yo go back, just try to refresh the page and see if you are still getting that page? I think it's just a browser cache and nothing else.

Comment: After refreshing showing login page only but on click of back it should go to login page. It should not load previous page from cache that's why i want to clear cache. Is there any way in React clear cache on logout

Comment: As I already said it might be browser cache only. Your code is working as expected.

Comment: Yes, but i need to clear browser cache

Answer (score -1):

You could put this inside the head tag to clean the Browser cache:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

As stated in this article:

[https://thewebdev.info/2021/10/03/how-to-clear-browser-cache-in-react/#:~:text=To%20clear%20browser%20cache%20in%20React%2C%20we%20can%20add%20meta,the%20page%20isn't%20cached.&text=in%20the%20head%20tag%20to,make%20sure%20nothing%20is%20cached](https://thewebdev.info/2021/10/03/how-to-clear-browser-cache-in-react/#:%7E:text=To%20clear%20browser%20cache%20in%20React%2C%20we%20can%20add%20meta,the%20page%20isn%27t%20cached.&text=in%20the%20head%20tag%20to,make%20sure%20nothing%20is%20cached).

Comment: User still wants cache functionality - he only wants it cleared on logout